# PHP variable variable array key list

Tags: php, variables, multidimensional-array, key

I have a multidimensional array where this works:

```
print_r( $temp[1][0] );
```

How can I make this work... I have the list of keys as a string like this:

```
$keys = "[1][0]";
```

I want to access the array using the string list of keys, how can it be done?
This works but the keys are obviously hard coded:

```
$keys = "[1][0]";
$tempName = 'temp';

print_r( ${$tempName}[1][0] );

// tried lots of variations like, but they all produce errors or don't access the array
print_r( ${$tempName.${$keys}} );
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Congratulations. You've just set my new personal record for fundamentally broken idea/code I've seen on SO. "Variable variables are neat, but let's see how far we can take them..."

Answer (score 4):

```
function accessArray(array $array, $keys) {
    if (!preg_match_all('~\[([^\]]+)\]~', $keys, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException;
    }

    $keys = $matches[1];
    $current = $array;
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $current = $current[$key];
    }

    return $current;
}

echo accessArray(
    array(
        1 => array(
            2 => 'foo'
        )
    ),
    '[1][2]'
); // echos 'foo'
```

Would be even nicer, if you passed in `array(1, 2)`, instead of `[1][2]`: One could avoid the (fragile) `preg_match_all` parsing.

Comment: I like this approach because it is elegant and safe.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it "elegant", but at least it's safe ;)